# Spring Boot JPA how to retrieve data from a ManyToMany table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am learning Spring boot.
Now I have ManyToMany relationship with a User entity and a Team entity.
So an user can have several teams and a team can have several users.

```
   @Entity
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id", nullable =false, updatable = false)
        private Long id;
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "team_have",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teamId"))
    List<Team> haveTeams;
```

This is the Team entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEAM")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long teamId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="team")
    private List<Task> tasks;
```

This is my repository:

```
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Long>{
    List<Team>findByName(String name);
    
}
```

How can I find all teams which belonged to one user?

Comment: add this to your team repo: List<Team>findByUser(User user);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User already have mapped with `List<Team>`, you need to use `UserRepository` instead of `TeamRepository`.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByName(String name);
    
}
```

Here, you will get one user and that user have all teams which he belongs to. (Assuming username is unique)

OR

If you are having bidirectional Many-to-Many (Team also mapped `Lis<User>`) like following

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEAM")
public class Team {

    ....
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="haveTeams")
    private List<User> users;
```

Then you can define query method like following to get all teams for one user,

```
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Long>{
    List<Team> findByUsers(User user);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build the connection between them would be to use a bi-directional relationship, like this:

`User Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    /* @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) You don't need this, 
    the name is taken from the name of the variable and it cannot be null since you 
    have @GeneratedValue */
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_team", // I would name this user_team since the user can have many teams, and vice versa
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id" , referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id",  referencedColumnName = "id"))
     Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`Team Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long teamId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teams", fetch = LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`Team Repo`

```
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Long>{
     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM team t1 INNER JOIN user_team t2 ON t1.id = t2.team_id WHERE t2.user_id = ?1 ")
    List<Team> findAllByUserId(long userId);
}
```

Example of use:

```
List<Team> teams = teamRepo.findAllByUserId(1);
```

A great tutorial:
https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-mapping